# react.js overlay not working - only displaying parent object

Tags: reactjs, overlay

I'm just trying to create an overlay from raw with react.

So I created an empty `Overlay` Component for now. One `App` Component, which has the data(a simple line) to be displayed for the normal time.

Now I rendering `<Overlay><App/></Overlay>`

But the from App is not being rendered?

What is wrong here, actually ?

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/embed/funny-turing-xkd3d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Please provide proper link of codesandbox or post code here

Comment: @NirajKaushal it's a valid link : https://codesandbox.io/embed/funny-turing-xkd3d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Why not use a third party ready made solutions like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-overlay ?

Comment: @EvgeniiKlepilin i'm actually trying to get myself familiarized with 'everything you should know about react.js'.. that's why i'm trying to create this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in return of `Overlay` component. Please replace your return statement with `<div className="overlay">{this.props.children}<div>`

You have to write css for class `overlay`.

Answer (score 1):

You cant create an overlay in such a way. The best way would be to create a higher order component and then return the new component with it.

https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html